# Disable button for X minutes

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a button with a link that people can click once every 5 minutes.

However, I want to replace the text of the button from "Click" (when it's enabled) to "Please wait Y:XX" (when it's disabled).

As an example, I click the button and the value of the button will be:
**Please wait 5:00 minutes.**
**Please wait 4:59 minutes.**

...and going down until it reaches 0:00 when the button will be available again.

Could anyone please help me ?

Comment: that is an amazing site if you can retain a visitor for 5 minutes

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially set a cookie with a timestamp in it. When the user clicks the button, check the current time against the value set in the cookie and display that time. If it is after 5 minutes, allow the action to perform.

You could set a timer to check the cookie value every second to update the button text.